# Spacing/aligning system of linear equations using systeme

Tags: amsart, systeme

Below is a picture of a system of linear equations whose solution is shown. (See the first system.) Notice that on the left side, the $x$ in the first row and the $y$ in the second row are too close. Compare them to the $x$ and $y$ in the second system.

**Question:** Is it possible to space out the $x$ and $y$ in the first system so that their positions match those in the second system?

I tried using `\phantom`, but it did not help; it created too much space when compared to the second system.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\noindent Here is a system of linear equations whose solution is shown:
\[  
    \systeme[xyz]{x - z = 1, y + 2z = 3, z = 0}
    \quad \longrightarrow \quad
    \systeme*[xyz]{x = 1, y = 3, z = 0}
    \quad \longrightarrow \quad
    \text{point $(1,1,0)$.}
\]
The $x$ and $y$ on the left side are too close. Compare it to this system:
\[  
    \systeme[xyz]{x + y - z = 1, y + 2z = 3, z = 0}
    \quad \longrightarrow \quad
    \systeme*[xyz]{x = -2, y = 3, z = 0}
    \quad \longrightarrow \quad
    \text{point $(-2,1,0)$.}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The point given in the first system is typed incorrectly, but that's fine. The question on spacing still remains.

Answer (score 3):

A `\phantom` helps make it work.  Note I adjusted the notations of the second example to match those of the first, so that one can see the alignment matches up.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\noindent Here is a system of linear equations whose solution is shown:
\[  
    \systeme[xyz]{x \phantom{{}+{}} - z = 1, y + 2z = 3, z = 0}
    \quad \longrightarrow \quad
    \systeme*[xyz]{x = 1, y = 3, z = 0}
    \quad \longrightarrow \quad
    \text{point $(1,1,0)$.}
\]
The $x$ and $y$ on the left side are too close. Compare it to this system:
\[  
    \systeme[xyz]{x + y - z = 1, y + 2z = 3, z = 0}
    \quad \longrightarrow \quad
%    \systeme*[xyz]{x = -2, y = 3, z = 0}
    \systeme*[xyz]{x = 1, y = 3, z = 0}
    \quad \longrightarrow \quad
    \text{point $(1,1,0)$.}
%    \text{point $(-2,1,0)$.}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that `\hphantom{{}+{}}` is better.